# React - Reducing context data size using multiple contexts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

### INTRODUCTION

In my app **I have multiple contexts** for managing and storing state.

In one of my scenarios, I have noticed that, as I have a **UsersContext** (which stores the users data), it is not necessary to store the user data of each post creator in my **PostsContext**, **it could be better (for RAM) to just store its user id, and not to repeat the user data on it.**

I have thought to use "**parsers**" inside my reducers logic **before storing data**, in order to **remove the unnecessary fields of each object**.

Is this a good idea / is a common pattern?

### PROBLEM

The main problem I notice with this approach is: how to get the data correctly from both contexts? I mean, imagine the following component:

```
function Card({ content: { userData, image, description, location, date }) {
   ...
}
```

If I want to get the data from the contexts, and not from props, I have implemented two custom hooks (do not care about memoizations right now) which consumes a specific context:

```
/* HOOKS FOR GETTING SPECIFIC DATA FROM CONTEXT */

function useUpdatedPostData(postData) {
    const posts = usePosts(); <-- consume PostsContext

    return {
       ...postData,
       ...posts.getPost(postData.id) <--- Merging with data from context 
    }
}

function useUpdatedUserData(userData) {
    const users = useUsers(); <-- consume UsersContext

    return {
       ...userData,
       ...users.getUser(userData.id) <--- Merging with data from context 
    }
}


/* CONSUMER COMPONENT */

function Card({ content }) {
    // The main problem: ​
   ​const { 
      ​image,
      ​description,
      ​location,
      ​date,
   ​} = useUpdatedPostData(content);

  const { username, avatar } = useUpdatedUserData(content.userData);

  ...

}
```

**something which makes the code really difficult to read.** Any tips?

Comment: I think you would really benefit from using `reselect`. the `selector` concept they have is really useful for chaining data together from different sources, and it memoizes its results so its quite efficient. Happy to chat with you about this further if you're interested

Comment: @JohnRuddell never used this library, could you provide me an example? Is it possible to get specific segments of nested data?

Comment: so a selector has 2 arguments, `createSelector([getUsersContext, getPostsContext], (usersContext, postsContext) => { // build a data model here })` the first argument is an array of functions, they can be used to pull out the user and post context, the second argument is a function, its parameters will be the same length as the array of functions... and are the result of those functions when called. You can then use those contexts to combine data together and whatever is returned is what you can use in your view `const usersAndPosts = useSelector(usersAndPostsSelector);`

Comment: I started using this for my work to manage mapping large data sets together because it is really efficient and also composable. You can use selectors in selectors.

Comment: If you'd like to setup a codesandbox that has some dummy data I can help update it with a selector to show an example. You essentially add a *data presentation layer* in your application. Where you call these selectors and they handle data modeling for the views. Its a good system to write tests for as well :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell thx mate, the idea looks really similar to what I was doing, but easier! I will use it, there is no need for implementing the sandbox, I got it.